# How to clean an oily spot from the camera body?

Tags: cleaning, body, nikon-d5100

This is very trivial. You are eating some food, you grabbed your camera for some reasons and inadvertently you left an oily finger print on your camera. It should be easy to remove right? But it isn't.

I am not too concerned about the oily spot but I want to ask if there is a better way to clean it. This happened to me and I tried [Targus LCD Screen cleaner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001AJFWNK) (which makes my laptop brand new); did not work. I tried Windex; did not work. I though this is an oily spot so better use soap. I applied soap 3 times; still did not work.

Now I would say the mark has gone a bit less pronounced but it is not clean yet. Can someone explain the science of it, what it is not so easy to remove? When I apply a treatment, it disappears and then it reappears. Anyone know why?

I am attaching a pic of the mark:

[image: camera body with oil spot]

Comment: I'm going to remove the [tag:spots] tag because that's usually about spots as artifacts in images. This is more of a blotch or a splotch or a smear. :)

Comment: I knew but I thought this will give some interesting results to the user. Also resized the pic.

Comment: I have no idea what you ate.... Usually soap works. Otherwise try ROR (Residual Oil Remover) sold at good camera stores.

Comment: hahaha...What I do is wet my finger, roll it over the soap and apply it on the spot then wipe it with tissue paper. The spot does go away! and it looks clean but then it comes back! I just don't know what cameras are made off.

Comment: I would guess its not actually going away, its just that the surrounding camera body gets wet, and looks the same. If the camera body is porous material it may have absorbed whatever you got on it. Its also possible that whatever it is has hardened and bonded, and will require an appropriate solvent to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method really. What you need is some alcohol based substance(NO! not Jack!) some deodorant would do. Apply some of it on the affected area, and wipe with a clean cloth. Should be gone in a few seconds! :)

Answer (score 1):

If alcohol won't work, the next level of attack would be product like **Goo Gone** (an orange oil product; note, this is not "Goof Off," that's a different product) or perhaps acetone (nail polish remover). Anything stronger, though, and you risk damaging the plastic, for example "Goof Off" — that stuff softens plastic and will ruin the finish.

Comment: I am not so worried about the spot (I am just a guy). I thought someone would know the science of it, why it gets removed by soap and reappears again. Will try some other stuff. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Well, if no cleaner will touch it, then something has physically damaged the finish of the plastic like a solvent or it's a varnish-like thing that has essentially "painted" the surface. I can't really think of what food item would do that. Perhaps a spice mixed in a food oil did it. Or it could be aliens.